# TypeScript: Using conditional type without type variables

Tags: typescript

Given a union of:

```
type Status =
    | "Loading"
    | "Success"
    | "Error"
```

I was expecting this to work:

```
type Success = Status extends "Success" ? Status : never;
const s: Success = "Success";
```

However, the above results in

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Whereas, if I use what I thought was an equivalent:

```
type E<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
type Success = E<Status, "Success">;

const s: Success = "Success";
```

It compiles without a problem. Now, I know that the `E` type I've created is pretty much how `Extract` works. I'd just like to understand, what makes it behave differently in the above two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the conditional type distributes over the union, so `E<"Loading" | "Success" | "Error", "Success">` is resolved as

```
E<"Loading", "Success"> | E<"Success", "Success"> | E<"Error", "Success">
// "Success"
```

and not as

```
"Loading" | "Success" | "Error" extends "Success" ? "Loading" | "Success" | "Error" : never
// never
```

For more information, see the [TypeScript handbook section on Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).